# How to get following data via SQL

Tags: sql, join, select

I was struggling on how to get the following data.

I have 2 tables:

```
 |  Company Name  | Customer ID 1 | Customer ID 2 | Customer ID 3
 +----------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------
 |    Android     |       1       |       2       |      3
 |      IOS       |       4       |       5       |      6
```

And the following table

```
 |  Customer ID | Customer Name |
 +--------------+---------------+
 |      1       |     Edwin     |     
 |      2       |     Stanley   |       
 |      3       |     Roward    |        
 |      4       |      Kim      |      
 |      5       |     Flare     |       
 |      6       |     Queen     |
```

How can I get the result such as this in SQL query?

```
 |  Company Name  | Customer Name1 | Customer Name2 | Customer Name3
 +----------------+----------------+----------------+---------------
 |    Android     |     Edwin      |    Stanley     |      Roward
 |      IOS       |       Kim      |     Flare      |      Queen
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Comment: A join table between customers and companies, rather than multiple customer ID columns, is easier to work with. Look into many-to-many relationships.

Comment: A more flexible design would be to use an [associative entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity), then you could have any number of users associated with a company

Comment: -GMB will do, next time will be aware
-Schwern Yah was trying to join but obtain multiple of data that i did not need since im not quite used to inner join
-Phil OK will look into it for further reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join, join ... and join:

```
select
    t.company_name,
    c1.customer_name customer_name1,
    c2.customer_name customer_name2,
    c3.customer_name customer_name3
from mytable t
inner join customers c1 on c1.customer_id = t.customer_id1
inner join customers c2 on c2.customer_id = t.customer_id2
inner join customers c3 on c3.customer_id = t.customer_id3
```

An important thing here is to use different table aliases for each join to avoid conflicts on the table that is joined multiple times.

Comment: Thank you so so much, was struggling how to inner join everything together.